# Post XML as "application/xml" instead of "text/xml" via RestSharp

Tags: c#, web-services, salesforce, content-type, restsharp

I'm hooking into the [Salesforce Bulk API](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Bulk_API) using [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/).

When I add an object using `AddBody`:

```
var request = new RestRequest( Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;
request.AddHeader("X-SFDC-Session", loginresult.SessionID);
var ji = new jobInfo { operation = "insert", @object = "contact", contentType = "CSV" };
request.AddBody(ji, xmlns);
```

Salesforce rejects it with this error message:

> Unsupported content type: text/xml

... presumably because behind the scenes RestSharp is interpreting `request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Xml;` as "text/xml".

By fiddling around with the Salesforce API I have discovered that it wants "application/xml" instead of "text/xml".

Is there a supported way to make RestSharp send "application/xml" instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest#requestbody)

> RequestBody
>
> If this parameter is set, its value will be sent as the body of the
>   request. Only one RequestBody Parameter is accepted – the first one.
>
> The name of the parameter will be used as the Content-Type header for
>   the request.

So:

```
var ji = new jobInfo { operation = "insert", @object = "contact", contentType = "CSV" };

var jiSerialized = /* Serialize ji to XML format */

request.AddParameter(new Parameter
{
    Name = "application/xml",
    Type = ParameterType.RequestBody,
    Value = jiSerialized 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the solution offered by [@Paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28674618/1497596), using RestSharp version 105.2.3, I have found that the following will change the `Content-Type` of a request from `text/xml` to `application/xml`:

```
request.AddBody(ji, xmlns);
request.Parameters[0].Name = "application/xml"; // default is "text/xml"
```

Here's what I see for `request.Parameters[0]` in the Visual Studio debugger after doing the above:

```
ContentType    null
Name           "application/xml"
Type           RequestBody
Value          "<YourSerializedXmlDocHere>...</YourSerializedXmlDocHere>"
```

As you can see, `ContentType` is null which seems a little troubling to me. But as @Paddy indicates, the RestSharp documentation says that "The ***name of the parameter*** will be used as the Content-Type header for the request."